# Writing content at a specific position using QFile

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to use a file on a hard drive (instead of a buffer in memory) to store matrix like numbers. E.g. at index 15 write number 20.

To do so, I thought I can use QFile and QTextStream (or QDataStream), open the file, seek to position 0, then seek to position 15 (in this example) and write number 20, then close the file.

My problems are:

1. opening the file a second time with file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) deletes the former content
2. opening the file a second time with file.open(QIODevice::Append) disables the seek functionality

Do you know a proper solution without creating a copy of the file in memory? Simply opening a stream, jumping to the correct position and writing content?

My simple code is:

```
file.setFileName("hyper_cube.dat");
if (!file.exists()){
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) return false;

    QTextStream out(&file);

    //write something into the file

    for (int i=0;i<ni;++i){
        for (int j=0;j<nj;++j){
            for (int k=0;k<nk;++k){
                out << qint32(0);
                out << qint32(0);
                out << qint32(0);
                out << qint32(0);
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();
}


//then later in the code and in another function
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QTextStream out(&file);

//file.seek(0); //you see, I tried the same with QFile - it also fails to jump to the right position
//file.seek(index);
out.seek(0);
out.seek(index);

out << qint32(a);
out << qint32(b);
out << qint32(c);
out << qint32(d);

file.close();
```

Comment: Writing in the middle of a file is dangerous. What if you use `QSettings` for your purpose?

Comment: If you have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevicebase.html#OpenModeFlag-enum you can see that WriteOnly erases the file content, you can combine it with ReadOnly to get what you want

Comment: QSettings is maybe a bit overloaded, I really just need a plain text (or byte array) on a hard drive, with which I can play. There are hardware restrictions not allowing me to have a lot of data in memory and the matrix is quite large.

Comment: @Odeaxcsh, that's it!!! Thank you.

Comment: You should add intermediate step. Write a piece of data to QByteArray, then write the QByteArray to the right position in the file.ä, checking lengths, zeroing unused bytes, etc. That way you have better control over the whole thing

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you can not _insert_ into the middle of a file. Not possoble. You can only overwrite and append. So what ever you do needs to work within these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

With the QIODevice Flags WriteOnly and ReadOnly I now have a solution which seems to work. I still do need to test some extreme cases. It was really just the combination of ReadOnly and WriteOnly, which did the magic.
Now reading from the file...

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QDataStream in(&file);
in.device()->seek(0);
in.device()->seek(index);

qint16 a,b,c,d;

in >> a;
in >> b;
in >> c;
in >> d;

file.close();
```

...and writing to the file...

```
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QDataStream out(&file);

out.device()->seek(0);
out.device()->seek(index);

out << qint16(a);
out << qint16(b);
out << qint16(c);
out << qint16(d);

file.close();
```

...somehow works.

I use QDataStream to have a fixed length per entry. In my simple understanding, this should do the job. The index is for sure taking into consideration that I write 4 int16 variables instead of just one.